# How to git push without credentials?

Tags: php, git, github, credentials, git-push

I'm new to git and github and would like to know how to git push `login-credentials.php` without Username and Password in it.

Suppose, there are just two files on local repository and `index.php` will `include ("login-redentials.php");`:

```
index.php
login-credentials.php
```

When using `git push origin master`, both files will be pushed to github. In this case, USERNAME and PASSWORD will be made published.

What is the best way to remove login credentials from `login-credentials.php` BEFORE using `git push`? - I could not find a best practice for this use case in git documentation.

Comment: [`.gitignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

Comment: Be aware that if you ever *did* commit the file, listing its name in `.gitignore` to prevent committing further copies of it is not sufficient. The existing commits that do have it, still have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to totally ignore the files, you should add them to your [`.gitignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).

If you wish to "hide" only the credentials, that depends on your deployment and your build process. One way is using a vault (again, depending on your system).

Another option would be reading credentials from some environment variable, that'll be set in a secured manner somewhere else.

Comment: What do you mean with "using a vault"? - Can you illustrate that a little bit?